# Loop thru ExcelPackage result for linq

Tags: c#, epplus

Below code will query the specified condition within the sheet using EPPlus. Note that the result will have 2 columns.

```
var objs = from cell in worksheet.Cells["a:a"]
where cell.Value.ToString().Contains(textKey)
select worksheet.Cells["a:b"];
```

How will I loop through column [2] of the result like something below?

```
foreach (var item in objs[columnn 2])
{
    textKeys.Add(item.Value.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Why do you check for cells in the Range A:A but then select *all* values in A:B?

Comment: I need to get the values in col B for later use in querying on the data layer.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but you can simply use `select cell` and later check for the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objs` contains the list of records with both the columns interchangeably like A1, B1, A2, B2... Please check if below works for you:

```
   var result = objs.FirstOrDefault();

   if (result != null && result.Any())
   {
      var filterResult = result.Where(x => x.Address.Contains("B")); 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. Marking this as an answer.